# dnsmasq local TTL countdown and refresh

Tags: dnsmasq

dnsmasq has a feature called local-ttl which you can hard code to a particular number of seconds.  By doing so it then sets DNS requests to the TTL you specified.

However, the TTL value every time you query is the same hard coded value, is it possible to configure it so that it does a countdown starting from the value you specified to 0, then once it reaches 0 to read from the local files again and restart the countdown ?

So the order of steps would be.

1. Read from the local host files
2. Start the initial TTL using the value from local-ttl
3. Count down the TTL so that when you do a query it shows the time remaining
4. When the TTL gets to 0 it refreshes the local cache (reads the local hosts files again)
5. The process repeats